# Nodejs how to optimize writing very large xml files?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a huge CSV (1,5GB) which I need to process line by line and construct 2 xml files. When I run the processing alone my program takes about 4 minutes to execute, if I also generate my xml files it takes over 2.5 hours to generate two 9GB xml files.

My code for writing the xml files is really simple, I use `fs.appendFileSync` to write my opening/closing xml tags and the text inside them. To sanitize the data I run this function on the text inside the xml tags.

```
  function() {
    return this.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
      .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
      .replace(/'/g, "&apos;");
  };
```

Is there something I could optimize to reduce the execution time?

Comment: Do you mean you're calling `fs.appendFileSync()` for every line in your CSV file?

Comment: @robertklep yes, should I try to buffer my lines and call appendFileSync only once in a couple of lines?

Answer (score 2):

`fs.appendFileSync()` is a relatively expensive operation: it opens the file, appends the data, then closes it again.

It'll be faster to use a [writeable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscreatewritestreampath-options):

```
const fs = require('node:fs');

// create the stream
const stream = fs.createWriteStream('output.xml');

// then for each chunk of XML
stream.write(yourXML);

// when done, end the stream to close the file
stream.end();
```

Comment: I'm opening the file only once and using the same file descriptor for all the appendFileSync calls, which according to the source code eliminates the need to openSync and closeSync the file for each call. But I'll give writeStream a go too, maybe there's still an improvement.

Comment: the path argument can also be a file descriptor https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/ec1c61662eb0483dee256f0fd492c3ce955f1335/lib/fs.js#L2243

Comment: @Paul yeah I just noticed! Sorry for the confusion :D In that case, I wonder if using a stream will be much faster. But at least it will provide some buffering, which might still speed things up (at least it will not block the event loop).

Answer (score 0):

I drastically reduced the execution time (to 30 minutes) by doing 2 things.

1. Setting the ENV variable UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=64
2. Buffering my writes to the xml file (I flush the buffer to the file after 20,000 closed tags)